# Find a power series representation of the function $\frac{3x^2+4x-5}{x(x+1)(x^2+x+1)}.$

Tags: power-series

I'm trying to find the power series representation for:

> $$f(x)\;=\;\frac{3x^2+4x-5}{x(x+1)(x^2+x+1)}$$

without a reasonable solution.

Any help you could give me will be appreciated.

Comment: About which point?

Comment: The function has a pole at zero and is undefined there. Similarly, there are other poles coming from the roots of the denominator. However, if you allow Laurent series, you can express it as a power series but with an extra term for the pole. So, in this case you have $f(x ) = -5/x + 14 - 15x + ...$.

Comment: But there is one Laurent series for the region $0 < |x| < 1$ and a different one for $|x| > 1$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT** Expand the function in partial fractions

$$
-\frac{x+2}{x^2+x+1}+\frac{5}{x}-\frac{4}{x+1}
$$

And expand each term. For instance

$$
\frac{1}{x+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^k x^k ~~~\mbox{for}~~~ |x| < 1
$$

can you take it from here?

Comment: You won't be able to expand $5/x$ in a power series about $x=0$.

Comment: @JairTaylor That's absolutely right. The region of convergence needs to be specified for all terms

Answer (score 0):

**Major components**

This should be etched into memory:
$$
 \frac{1}{x+1} = 1 - x + x^{2} - x^{3} + x^{4} + \dots
$$
Notice the missing powers are $2, 8, 14, \dots$
$$
 \frac{1}{x^{2}+x+1} = 1 - x + x^{3} - x^{4} + x^{6} - x^{7} \dots
$$

**Assemble using multiplication**

Missing powers are $3, 4, 9, 10, 15, 16, \dots$
$$
\frac{1}{x \left( x+1 \right)\left( x^{2}+x+1 \right)} = 
\frac{1}{x} - 2 + 2 x - x^{2} + x^{5} - 2x^{6} + 2x^{7} - x^{8} + x^{11} + \dots
$$

Final answer:
$$
\frac{3x^{2} + 4x - 5}{x \left( x+1 \right)\left( x^{2}+x+1 \right)} = 
-\frac{5}{x} +14 - 15 x+ 7x^{2} + 2x^{3} - 3x^{4} - 5x^{5} + 14x^{6} -15 x^{7} + \dots
$$

[image: plot]